# Modifying existing geometry type or create new geometry type in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, st-geometry

I want to modify PostGIS geometry type TRIANGLE by adding additional information about its neighbours within TIN.

WKT representation might look as follows: TRIANGLEN ((0 0 0,1 1 1,1 0 2,0 0 0) ID n1 n2 n3), where ID is identifier of the current triangle and n1, n2, n3 are IDs of adjacent triangles.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Composite types see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rowtypes.html could be answer or User defined types see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xtypes.html.

And why not use table like geometry , neighbors(array) + other columns. That solves same problem ( me thinks)